# Make phone call without getting phone number (click icon to call) in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I'm currently working on my 2nd program and stuck with phone calling, sending SMS, emailing, and showing location using Google Map. I'm using `ImageButton`s for all of these. User doesn't need to type any numbers or addresses (not using `EditText` to get user input). However, it doesn't work.

For example, when user click on Phone icon, it will make a call. However, I still need a user input (the actual message, not the destination number or email address) for sending SMS and email. I can do it if I use `EditText`. However, without using `EditText`, I cannot do it. How do I do this? I've added users permission in manifest file.

**PhoneActivity .java**

```
public class PhoneActivity extends Activity {

        ImageButton btnphonecall;
        String phoneNumber = "091111111";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone);

            btnphonecall=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

            btnphonecall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                    i.setData(Uri.parse("091111111"));
                                    PhoneActivity.this.startActivity(i); 
                //I've tried startActivity(i) along but still doesn't work 
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I just needed to add "tel:" haha. I spent 3 hours to figure this out... lol I was actually little mad....... Thank you so much~~~

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:"+091111111 );
Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                                    number);
dial.setPackage("com.android.phone");
PhoneActivity.this.startActivity(dial);
```

Comment: I am not sure if that its compulsory to specify the package

Comment: @Kirill: yes my friend its not compulsory if you specify this then call will be done by android default dialer.